# Getting xDebug listed on WampServser Debug Menu

Tags: php, xdebug, wampserver

OK, been banging my head against the wall again for a few days. Trying to follow a suggestion from another answer on SO here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955822/php-file-caching-vs-cache-through-htaccess . In trying to set up a local test environment with xDebug, I downloaded WampServer because it said that it was a complete package that came with xDebug included. I have tried various settings in PHP.ini, but cannot get xDebug to appear on the Debug menu of WampServer. I saw an image of a Wamp menu that had it listed in the Debug menu, along with WebGrind that I do have, but cannot accomplish the same feat.

Here are my current PHP.ini settings for xDebug (that includes a few rem'd out):

```
; XDEBUG Extension

;zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9.dll"

zend_extension = c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.3-vc9.dll

[xdebug]
xdebug.default_enable = On ;added
xdebug.remote_enable = On ;Off
xdebug.remote_port = 9000 ;added
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp" ;added
xdebug.remote_host="localhost" ;added
xdebug.profiler_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = On ;Off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp" ;added

;xdebug.show_local_vars=On
;xdebug.dump.SERVER=HTTP_HOST, SERVER_NAME
;xdebug.dump_globals=On
;xdebug.collect_params=4

;xdebug.show_local_vars=1
```

Yes, I am aware that there are two separate PHP.ini files in Wamp, but making the change in both does nothing.

I have tried the "custom installation" instructions on the xDebug website, but that does not do anything.

phpinfo file lists it as being installed.

I can find the xDebug client in the Wamp tool's folder and open it, but the open file option on the xDebug menu is grayed out and does not work.

I have explored and tried various solutions found here on the SO website, but still no joy.

I even found a nice step by step installation webpage for WampServer and xDebug here http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/WampServer_HowTo.html, but all I succeeded in doing was downloading another very large program called eclipse, installing and configuring that, but still nothing. This does appear to be a nice looking program, but after doing the configuration, it does not seem to associate with wampserer either.

xDebug and wampserver do appear to be very common issues asked here on SO...so any ideas that actually work???

BTW: is there any way of increasing the font size in this question and comments box here on SO, so I do not have to use a magnifying glass to see what I am typing??? I know that it is repeated down below but it is a lot easier to see what you are typing, where you are typing...just my two cents...

Thanks for any assistance,

Stan...

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following these Steps**

1. Open your Wamp Server phpinfo() page.
2. Copy Evrything in it Using a Big Control+A and the Paste it in the xDebug Wizard. Here is the link

http://xdebug.org/wizard.php

Now Download the DLL file provided by the Wizard and put it in your wamp/bin/php/php/ext folder.

Paste the Following Code in your php.ini file at the very end...

**NOTE: use php.ini under wamp/bin/apache/apache/bin/php.ini**

```
zend_extension="C:/Softwares/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/ext/php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9.dll"

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

Hope this works fine for you. I got this information after working 3 to 4 days to get xDebug on NetBeans. :)

Comment: Hi Vijay Sarin, Thank you for your thoughts, but as listed above, I have already tried all of this and nothing...

Comment: Change your Zend Path. You are Using Back Slashes. Change it to Forward Slashes. Also Try Using Quotes

Comment: Sorry, was on Vacation for few days. Hey, Have you tried disabling the User Access Control Feature. For me this worked when i tried to configure in Office laptop. Go to Control Panel. In that Action Center. In the Left Pane you can see change user Access Control settings link. Click on that and Make sure your User Access Control is Disabled temporarily. Reboot and try. This should work i hope.

Comment: Hi Vijay, Thanks for hanging in here with me and I hope that you enjoyed your vacation. Do anything fun? OK, I opened up Wampserver, but cannot find any Control Panel in it?? If you are talking about Windows Control Panel on my laptop, then I am on XP Pro and do not see the steps that you list...Thanks again, Stan...

Comment: In Case of windows XP, the above steps are of no use... Whenever i got up with a new error with xDebug, i used to remember this POST. Also, Have you checked your PHP Setting in CMD. I mean is the ENV Variables set up in Windows for PHP. Also, Can u check if user has full control over the wamp directory.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the "" from ***zend_extension***
2. Remove ; infront of **zend_extension**

And finally use this code in PHP.ini both files.

[xdebug]

```
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"

xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
```

Answer (score -1):

To work with `xdebugclient`, you need to add `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=session_name` as a parameter to the URL, where `session_name` is the name of your debug session.